# ProgressDialog over a WebView appears dimmed

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I have a WebView in my Android app which displays a web page with a specific URL. The URL is a signal to the app to close the WebView and perform other actions.

I'd like to display a ProgressDialog over the WebView while the app loads the functions required by the URL. However when the ProgressDialog appears, it appears dimmed, as if there is an overlay superimposed on top of it. Displaying an AlertDialog appears as normal. Can anyone advise why the PD appears dimmed?

```
private class WebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, final String url) {
        if (url.contains("my/special/url")) {
            // ProgressDialog message appears dimmed
            ProgressDialog progress;
            progress = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
            progress.setMessage("Loading...");
            progress.show();
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            // AlertDialogs appear as normal
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            AlertDialog dialog;
            builder.setMessage("Loading");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a bright color to show progress or you can elevate it so that it'll come to the top `android:elevation="20dp"` above every layer

Answer (score 0):

In your code your private Inner class name is `WebView`that need to change.
It could be `MyWebView` or anything else. But should not `WebView`.

Because,

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, final String url) {

}
```

In this override method there is a paramiter `WebView` that is build in class in android from `android.webkit` package.

If you keep your class name `WebView` that means you not overriding method form `WebViewClient` `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`and it will not work.

### Then

You can override `onPageStarted` to show your progress dialog
because it call on loading the page....

```
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if (url.contains("my/special/url")) {
            // ProgressDialog message appears dimmed
            ProgressDialog progress;
            progress = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
            progress.setMessage("Loading...");
            progress.show();
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            // AlertDialogs appear as normal
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            AlertDialog dialog;
            builder.setMessage("Loading..");
        }
    }
```

You must ensure that `if (url.contains("my/special/url"))` is true. otherwise it never execute...because if(false) never execute ... in this case else part will execute if have..

Answer (score 0):

For showing progress in webview, WebViewChromeClient is used. Try to implement webview using below example. Hope it solves your problem.

```
public class webView extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String mUrl;
    public WebView mWebView;
    // public ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;//

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);
        Log.e("Webview class", "I'm in web view");

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        //set progress bar max limit
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        //get the url from the intent of this activity called from the fragments
        mUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
        // set the title of webview to be th url
        setTitle(mUrl);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

        //setContentView(mWebView);

    }

    private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressBar.setProgress(100);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }

    private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }

    }
}
```